# Smooth TGraph2D with kernel regression or similar?

Tags: root-framework

I see that TGraphSmoother has Nadaraya-Watson kernel regression smoothing (and other forms of kernel-based smoothing).  However, it looks to me like this will only work properly on a TGraph, not a TGraph2D.

Are there any tools appropriate for smoothing a TGraph2D? The data in my TGraph2D is noisy, so I need more than just interpolation. Or is the best choice to develop my own adaptation of the TGraphSmoother algorithm with support for TGraph2Ds?

Comment: maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you can read in root data with [root_numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/root_numpy/) and then use [scipy's image library](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tool that can handle multi-dimensional pdf smoothing in RooFit, for example `RooNDKeysPdf` - see https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classRooNDKeysPdf.html . To use it with a `TGraph2D`, the procedure would be to make a `RooDataSet` with a data point corresponding to each point in your graph, then use the `createHistogram` method to get a 2d histogram (`TH2`) of the smoothed distribution, from which you could re-create your graph. This might be overkill for your problem though..

Comment: A quick looks suggests this is probably not overkill at all. My problem involves interpolation using noisy calibration data with nonuniform density over the detector. This RooFit tool looks like it has exactly that case in mind. Many thanks!

Comment: After getting around to actually implementing this: RooNDKeysPdf takes a very long time for data sets as small as 100k events (now using it for a 3D function, so 4 total dimensions). That may force me to look into other options.

Comment: Yes, it can take quite a while. I know some people in the ATLAS Collaboration did some work on making some improvements to the algorithm and some approximations to speed things up, but I don't think it is publicly available (yet).

Comment: You could try without using adaptive mode (pass in an empty string as the "options" constructor argument). This will significantly speed things up (I think it goes from O(N^2D) to O(N^D)), and depending on your function may make little difference to the result. "Adaptive" mode means that the kernel width is adapted depending on the local density of the function. This is only needed where the width of features in the distribution varies widely.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to pass in binned data rather than every single event. The current version of the class doesn't let you pass in a RooDataHist unfortunately, but you can create a binned pseudo-dataset by creating events with coordinates of the bin centres and weights according to the bin contents. This worked pretty well for me in the past, and using e.g. 1k "bins" gave near identical results to passing in 100k events.

Comment: Thanks! I think adaptive mode is important for us, since some regions may have sparse data (hard to access with calibration source), but the converse of that is there are regions where there's tons of data. A binned approach would work well--3 dimensions of fine binning may be a lot of bins, but I imagine I can leave out the empty ones

I don't actually need a density estimator--a regression is good enough for our purposes, and I'd imagine a regression of a function of three variables would go faster than finding the PDF of four. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell RooFit will only do the PDF.